# HTTP client C library for Linux and Windows, redistributable without requiring attribution

Tags: windows, linux, library, http

I am looking for a HTTP client library that supports both Linux and Windows. I shall be using it in our commercial project and that's why don't want to use cURL (which is redistributable but requires attribution). The library should support following features:

1. HTTP keep-alive support.
2. HTTPS support (it is OK if it is OpenSSL based like cURL).
3. Proxy Support.
4. Library should be high performance.

Comment: cURL use this license which allows it to be re-used in commercial projects: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html

Comment: What kind of license do you want? Typical proprietary EULA licenses would prevent you from redistributing it. So any license that allows redistribution? Is attribution OK?

Comment: What programming language do you want to use the library from? C? Java? Python?

Comment: Our product is a cloud (SaaS) licensing library that our customers integrate with their respective products and if we use cURL then our customers will also have to give credit in their product documentation and that's why we want to avoid this situation. We can even consider some useful paid library. Library should be in C.